# Why my Loader is not working when I am giving all correct code

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, jsp

My loader and form is not showing when I am using pressing button.My loader is outside form still it is not working. Please help me I tried it to solve many time but I couldn't .I am adding here my signup.jsp and Register.java  code details here. I have added Threadsleep(3000) to hold loader for 3 seconds still it is not working

````
package com.user;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.sql.*;

public class Register extends HttpServlet {

   protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
           throws ServletException, IOException {
       response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
       try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
           /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
           /*out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
           out.println("<html>");
           out.println("<head>");
           out.println("<title>Servlet Register</title>");            
           out.println("</head>");
           out.println("<body>");*/
           //Getting all the details from incoming from request
           String name=request.getParameter("user_name");
           String email=request.getParameter("user_email");
           String password=request.getParameter("user_password");
           //out.println(name);
           //out.println(email);
           //out.println(password);
           //connection
            try{
                Thread.sleep(3000);
                Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
                Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/youtube1","root","Vandana");
                
                //query
                String q="insert into user(name,email,password) value(?, ?, ?)";
                PreparedStatement pstmpt= con.prepareStatement(q);
                pstmpt.setString(1, name);
                pstmpt.setString(2, password);
                pstmpt.setString(3, email);
           
                
                pstmpt.executeUpdate();
                
                out.println("Done");
            } 
            
            catch (Exception e){
               e.printStackTrace() ;
               out.println("Error");
            }

           
           
           //......
           //out.println("</body>");
           //out.println("</html>");
       }
   }

   // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
   /**
    * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
    *
    * @param request servlet request
    * @param response servlet response
    * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
    * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
    */
   @Override
   protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
           throws ServletException, IOException {
       processRequest(request, response);
   }

   /**
    * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
    *
    * @param request servlet request
    * @param response servlet response
    * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
    * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
    */
   @Override
   protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
           throws ServletException, IOException {
       processRequest(request, response);
   }

   /**
    * Returns a short description of the servlet.
    *
    * @return a String containing servlet description
    */
   @Override
   public String getServletInfo() {
       return "Short description";
   }// </editor-fold>

}

**signup.jsp** 

<%-- 
   Document   : signup
   Created on : 01-Feb-2022, 2:13:08 PM
--%>

<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
       <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
       <title>JSP Page</title>
       <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

       <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
       <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
           
   </head>
   <body style="background-image: url(images/bg.jpg); background-size: cover;background-attachment: fixed;">
       <div class="container">
           <div class="row">
               <div class="col m6 offset-m3">
                   
                   <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-content">
                            <div class="form center-align">
                                <h3 style="margin-top: 10px;"class="center-align">Register Here !!</h3>
                                <h5 id="msg" class="center-align"</h5>
                               <div class="form">
                               <!-- creating form -->
                               <form action="Register" method="post" id="myform">
                                   <input type="text" name="user_name" placeholder="Enter user_name"\>
                                   <input type="password" name="user_password" placeholder="Enter password"\>
                                   <input type="email" name="user_email" placeholder="Enter your email"\>
                                   
                                   <button type="submit" name="btn" style="background-color:#b3e5fc;">Submit</button>
                                   
                               </form>
                               <div class="loader center-align" style="margin-top: 10px; display: none;" >
                                       <div class="preloader-wrapper big active">
                                           <div class="spinner-layer spinner-blue-only">
                                             <div class="circle-clipper left">
                                               <div class="circle"></div>
                                             </div><div class="gap-patch">
                                               <div class="circle"></div>
                                             </div><div class="circle-clipper right">
                                               <div class="circle"></div>
                                             </div>
                                           </div>
                                     
                                           
                                   <h5>Please Wait....</h5>
                               </div>
                               
                           </div>
                   </div>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
     </div> 
   </div>
       <script
           src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
           integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4="
           crossorigin="anonymous">
               
       </script>
       <script>
               $(document).ready(function(){
               console.log("Page is ready...... ") ;
               $("#myform").on('submit',function(event){
               event.preventDefault();
               var f = $(this).serialize();
               console.log(f);
               $(".loader").show();
               $(".form").hide();
                    
                   $.ajax({
                      url:"Register",
                      data:f,
                      type:'POST',
                      success:function(data,textStatus,jqXHR){
                          console.log(data);
                          console.log("Success......");
                          $(".loader").hide();
                          $(".form").show();
                          if(data.trim()==="Done"){
                              $("#msg").html("Succesfully Registered !!!");
                              $("#msg").addClass("green-text");
                          }else{
                              $("#msg").html("Something went wrong !!!");
                              $("#msg").addClass("red-text");
                          }
                          
                      },
                      error:function(jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown){
                          console.log(data);
                          console.log("error");
                          $(".loader").hide();
                          $(".form").show();
                          $("#msg").html("Something went wrong !!!");
                          $("#msg").addClass("red-text");
                      }
                  });   
               });
               });
      
       </script>
   </body>
</html>```

please help
````

Comment: As your loader class is in form class, so it is hiding when you hide form class. keep the loader class outside of form class.

Comment: Loader outside form class please check carefully

Comment: Have you check your log files?

Comment: Yes  @ScaryWombat

Answer (score 0):

[image]

No, it is not outside.
you have used form class at two places.
Loader is outside of form, not outside from form class. please check image

Edit:

```
error:function(jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown){
                          console.log(data);
                          console.log("error");
                          $(".loader").hide();
                          $(".form").show();
                          $("#msg").html("Something went wrong !!!");
                          $("#msg").addClass("red-text");
                      }
```

Remove console.log(data); from your error function.
Still not working then check the console for any error

Comment: And also check data in success.

Comment: loader is visible now but form is still not visible after submit

Comment: when I am removing this code form is also visible      if(data.trim()==="Done"){
                               $("#msg").html("Succesfully Registered !!!");
                               $("#msg").addClass("green-text");
                           }else{
                               $("#msg").html("Something went wrong !!!");
                               $("#msg").addClass("red-text");
                           }